# Store object in 2 dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to store a node object (Containing stuff like a x & y coordinate as well as a state) in a 2 dimensional array so I can access the object like this:

```
array_variable[x, y]
```

Unfortunatly, I do not know how to do this in python as I am quite new to it. Here is the relevant code:

```
class node:    
    def init(self, x, y, state):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.state = state;
```

```
from node import node;

class grid:
    def init(self, x, y):
        self.width = x;
        self.height = y;
        self.g = [x, y];


    def set_node(self, x, y, state):
        print(len(self.g));
        n = node();
        n.init(x, y, state);
        self.g[x][y] = n;
```

Comment: I fixed your indentation, but `init` needs to be `__init__`

Comment: Semicolons at the end of the lines are not necessary in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a 2d array with height y and width x filled with zeros using list comprehension like this:

```
foo = [[0 for _ in range(x)] for _ in range(y)]
```

You can store node objects to position y, x in this 2d array like this:

```
n = node()
foo[y][x] = n
```

You can access the object in position y, x from 2d array like this:

```
node = foo[y][x]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for that purpose by defining the data type as `object`:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.empty((3, 3), dtype=object)
array[0, 0] = Node(...)
```